# How Can I Remove "CiviCRM - " From Page Titles?

Tags: wordpress, admin, display

Via the [Change Wordpress Title](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9003/change-wordpress-title/9011#9011?newreg=c7fe08f2e3484253b9f22b935dcb6a69) question I found that the page with the "civicrm" slug is what is used for content replacement by CiviCRM.

If I want to remove the CiviCRM "prefix" to all the crm pages just simply removing the page title for the CiviCRM page in WordPress is not enough. Now I see " - Site Name".

Example URL:
http://localhost/testsite/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/ical&reset=1&list=1&html=1

Page's title " - Test Site" (without quotes).

Is there a way to prevent CiviCRM from prefixing the " - "?

**Update**:

After doing a quick search in the plugin for "' - '" in all the PHP files I'm seeing code like this:

```
CRM_Utils_System::setTitle($displayName . ' - ' . $activityName);
```

I'm thinking it's not possible. That string looks pretty hard-coded to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the site name as the title, you can filter it:

```
// add filter only when basepage has been parsed
add_action( 'civicrm_basepage_parsed', 'my_override_civi_title' );

function my_override_civi_title() {
  // for themes that use wp_title()
  add_filter( 'wp_title', 'my_page_title', 200, 1 );
  // for themes that use add_theme_support( 'title-tag' )
  add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'my_page_title_parts' );
}

function my_page_title( $title ) {
  return get_bloginfo( 'name' );
}

function my_page_title_parts( $parts ) {
  unset( $parts['title'] );
  unset( $parts['page'] );
  return $parts;
}
```

Your own theme's implementation will determine the final method used.

Comment: Found out that the CiviCRM page that is created and used for showing content was using its name.