# Titles of CiviCRM pages on Wordpress and subsequent title issues when shared via social media

Tags: social-media

This was [once posted before](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/how-do-i-get-pcps-to-look-right-when-shared-on-facebook) - not sure if work has been done in the past 3 years.

As [Andrew Hunt pointed out](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9003/change-wordpress-title), on wordpress you either embed content as short codes or you link directly to content using a URL such as http://yoursite.org/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1 These CiviCRM URLs actually take the page that's before the question mark and replace all the content.

Essentially if you are not using a shortcode on a wordpress page, you cannot have the title of the event, contribution, etc page display as the title. While this is not the case with Drupal, in Drupal the title will appear as it is supposed to.

Since sharing event links via social media displays the title of the event, rather than the title of the page. We always have to manually change them via facebook and other sites. Below are two examples using the calendar or civicrm event links.

The core issue is making sure that the event page displayed is actually the event title and not the wordpress page.

Using Civi 5 and Wordpress 4.9.6

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is still something you would need to implement on the Wordpress site of the equation - much as indicated in the other question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get PCPs to look 'right' when shared on Facebook?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/how-do-i-get-pcps-to-look-right-when-shared-on-facebook)

Comment: @HomoTechsual I already referenced the other stack exchange - its not a duplicate.

Comment: just referencing the other issue doesn’t make this not a duplicate. If you feel it isn’t a duplicate can you explain why?

Comment: So the answer is for the past 3 years - no work has been done on this in Wordpress @HomoTechsual

Comment: Thanks @themak - could you edit that into the question - it's useful information and it helps everyone to see what research you've looked at, what you've considered. Thanks and good question.